# Android: Does anyone know if Android's room database is credential encrypted?

Tags: android, kotlin

I currently have a BroadcastReceiver that receives the system action ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED. This is received when the phone is powered on and the user has not unlocked their phone yet. I have a service that I start in the foreground that then tries to access my room database. Except it fails once hitting the database call.

[According to Android](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot) credential encrypted storage is locked until the user unlocks the phone. But I don't know if that includes an internal room database to the app.

The only error I can find in the Logcat is this:

```
--------- beginning of crash
```

Which isn't very helpful.

I can't attach a debugger to it to see what the full error is since when I restart the phone the debugger instance is lost. I've also tried broadcasting the ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED through ADB but it gives a permission denied since that is a system action. So I'm relying on Logcat print statements in my code.

My app schedules alarms so that is why I'm trying to get their information and set them without the need for a device unlock. I could use BOOT_COMPLETED, but that means I'm relying on the user to unlock their phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to Android credential encrypted storage is locked until the user unlocks the phone. But I don't know if that includes an internal room database to the app.

If your Room database name is a simple name, then yes. If you supply a fully-qualified path, then it would depend upon where that path is pointing (assuming a path works — I haven't tried that recently...).

Room stores its databases in the default database location for Android's `SQLiteDatabase` class. That's on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), and it is part of credential-encrypted storage.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Guess I'll stick with BOOT_COMPLETED for the time being. A lot simpler to handle. Fingers crossed the user's phone doesn't crash and reboot in the middle of the night!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone, or even the OP, needs this information:

We just need to pass a device protected storage context as an argument to the Room.databasebuilder method.

```
private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): AlarmDatabase {
    val storageContext = context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext()
    return Room.databaseBuilder(
        storageContext,
        AlarmDatabase::class.java,
        "my_database"
    ).build()
}
```

The actual database file will then be created from this context, making it accessible even before the device is unlocked.